# How to zoom to particular section of a video in Android?

Tags: android, zooming, android-videoview, vitamio

I have a single video file in mp4 format that I can play in my Android project. Using Vitamio Bundle, I would like to zoom and focus to particular quadrant or section of the video.

[image]

Please see the illustration of the video in the image shown above. In this how to zoom to particular quadrant ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I also implemented video zoom on perticular part using
[this](http://father2sisters.blogspot.in/2014/07/resize-videoview-on-android-with-pinch.html)

try it.